# SMTP Mail with Java SSLSocket Text and Attachment

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp

So I am trying to send an Email with SSLSocket in Java through a SMTP-Server and want to send a message in the body and attachment together. I can send one or the other one but not both at the same time. I get no errors. It writes the text and the attachment as a text in the body. When I comment the text part out, it sends the attachment.

I searched a lot but only get hints with javamail, which I don't want to use. Any help please?

```
public void sendEmail(){
    String boundary = "__frontier";
    String boundary2 = "__frontier2";

    String fileName = "anhang.txt";
    String textTest ="Hello...i am here";
    try{
        sendCommandAndResultCheck("MAIL FROM: " + my_email_addr);
        sendCommandAndResultCheck("RCPT TO: " + recipient);
        sendCommandAndResultCheck("DATA");

        smtp_out.print("From: "+my_email_addr+"\r\n");
        smtp_out.print("To: "+recipient+ "\r\n");
        smtp_out.print("Subject: "+"Test \r\n");

        smtp_out.print("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");          
        smtp_out.print("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="+boundary);
        smtp_out.print("--"+boundary);
        smtp_out.print("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="+boundary2);
        smtp_out.print("--"+boundary2);
        smtp_out.print("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"");
        smtp_out.print("Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n");
        smtp_out.print(textTest);
        smtp_out.print("\r\n");
        smtp_out.print("--"+boundary2+"--");

        smtp_out.print("--"+boundary);
        smtp_out.print("Content-Type: application/text; name="+fileName+"\n");
        smtp_out.print("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n");
        smtp_out.print("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+fileName+"\n");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (new File("src/"+fileName)));
        String s = "";
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            s=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s.getBytes());
            smtp_out.print("\r\n"+s+"\r\n");
        }
        smtp_out.print("\r\n.\r\n");            
        smtp_out.print("--"+boundary+"--");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here the Email I get:

```
Hello...i am here
--__frontier2----__frontierContent-Type: application/text; name=anhang.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=anhang.txt

SXQgbWlnaHQgc2VlbSBjcmF6eSB3aGF0IEknbSAnYm91dCB0byBzYXk=

U3Vuc2hpbmUgc2hlJ3MgaGVyZSwgeW91IGNhbiB0YWtlIGEgYnJlYWs=

SSdtIGEgaG90IGFpciBiYWxsb29uIHRoYXQgY291bGQgZ28gdG8gc3BhY2U=

V2l0aCB0aGUgYWlyLCBsaWtlIEkgZG9uJ3QgY2FyZSBiYWJ5IGJ5IHRoZSB3YXk=

QmVjYXVzZSBJJ20gaGFwcHk=

Q2xhcCBhbG9uZyBpZiB5b3UgZmVlbCBsaWtlIGEgcm9vbSB3aXRob3V0IGEgcm9vZg==

QmVjYXVzZSBJJ20gaGFwcHk=

Q2xhcCBhbG9uZyBpZiB5b3UgZmVlbCBsaWtlIGhhcHBpbmVzcyBpcyB0aGUgdHJ1dGg=
```

I tried also to set `\r\n` at the end of some commands. But I don't really understand when I have to use them or not.

Comment: If you really want to create all of this manually instead of using a higher level library then please read the necessary standards instead of blindly guessing. There is already enough broken software out there because of such guess works. Relevant are MIME (RFC 2045..2048) and SMTP (RFC 5321).

Comment: Thanks but I already did that and according to what I understood from the RFCs should the code run.

Comment: Then please read again. You are at least missing several newlines around the boundaries and the base64 you send is broken too since it contains '=' in the middle of the encoded data and contains empty lines. Apart from that you are sending MIME boundary as an SMTP command.